# php curl proxy + follow redirect

Tags: php, curl, redirect, proxy, php-curl

i'm sending a curl request to a webpage that redirects 3 times

when i use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

it works well and responses with the last url & body in the third redirect ..

but when i use proxy

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $port);
```

the **CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION** doesn't work or i don't know .. 
the request doesn't go to the third url ..

**any idea why this is happening ?**

note that the  url uses https connection and i use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

to bypass it ..

**any idea why this is happening ?**

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE and post the VERBOSE log for both no-proxy (where it works) and proxy (where it does not work)